# Ext JS bug in WebKit Browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webkit, extjs4.1

I encountered a problem of declaring a variable "location" for extjs store where it runs without any problem in IE but browsers that has webkit like FireFox, Chrome..etc trying to redirected to unknown page with [object, object] in the end.

Was there any list of reserved variables like "location" we should not use it in extJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the different designs of 'Global' object in different browsers. 
In Chrome/Firefox/Opera, it will add the 'Global' object as a property to 'window'(host object). Like, 
`"var test = 'test';alert(window.test);"`,
the result will be: test. 
But, in IE, it doesn't add the global object to 'window'. 
So, here, the statement `var location = "Some value";` equals to `window.location = "Some value";`.

Comment: I agree and understood now how the js global variables execute in different browsers. Thanks Shen.       I also tested in IE 10, where it throws a silent js error - SCRIPT5039: Redeclaration of const property (just FYI)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Ext. The browser window object has a location property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I just tested without extJS references, declared a variable "location", same problem in browsers with WebKit. var location = "Some value";
        alert(location);Result: http://localhost:2510/Some%20value. So the problem is with Web-kit browsers that does not allow reserved variables?

Comment: There is no problem, this is just how the browser is implemented.  You should not be using a global variable called location.  You really shouldn't be using global variables at all.

Comment: I used the global variables because to reuse the objects without getting it every time especially to avoid getting the same object using Ext.getCmp() whenever required. I agree that we should avoid global variables but if a variable that needs to be reused across multiple functions then what would be the best way of implementing it other than passing as parameters to other functions?